# jQuery UI draggable containment area changes with screen size

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, draggable

I've got a large image that is held within a smaller div. The div has `position:absolute; top:10px; left:10px; width:563px; height:563px; z-index:200; overflow:hidden` applied to it so only a portion of the image is visible. The div lies within another div that centers the page on-screen with `width:1000px; margin:0 auto; position:relative;`

I've applied `$('#theImage').draggable({cursor: 'move', containment: [-523,-738,361,146]});` to the image, which means that it can be dragged around the div but the outer edges of the image never pass beyond the outer edges of the div. (i.e. the left edge of the image cannot be dragged beyond the left edge of the div, the same applies to the right, top and bottom edges) The image therefore always completely fills the div; no background is visible.

This works fine when my browser is maximised, but changes when it's not - I assume the containment X and Y values are calculated from the browser window, not the parent div. Is there any way I can force it to be calculated from the div? (Setting the containment to 'parent' doesn't work as it allows the image to be dragged right out of sight (i.e. each edge of the image can now be dragged as far as the opposite edge of the div).

Comment: Any chance you could make a demo at jsfiddle.net so it's easier to play around with and see the issue first hand? You can use a placeholder image of any size from lorempixel.com and include the jquery ui css under resources

Comment: I've created a demo at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dorianfabre/2EZ4A/), using the draggable image from my website. If the screen panels are set so that the result panel is half the width and just over half the height of my 1600x1200 monitor, the image scrolls perfectly within the div. However, if you change the size of the fiddle panel (or the browser window), the image will either not scroll all the way to the edge or go too far, showing background white. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and here is how I solved it:

```
var windowX = $( window ).width(); //determines the width of the browser window
var windowY = $( window ).height();//determines the height of the browser window
var imageX = 2000; //put the width of your image here. my image was 2000x1000
var imageY = 1000;//image height
$("#theImage").draggable({ containment: [(windowX - imageX),(windowY - imageY),0,0] });
```

the last line contains  your image between the top left corner and the width/height of the browser. hope this helps!